# Insert overwrite while other process write on same table

Tags: hive, hiveql

How the hive will behave if I use insert overwrite on `partitioned` `external` and `non partitioned` `external` table while other processes are writing into the same table?

I am trying below non partitioned table:

```
insert overwrite table customer_master (select * from customer_master);
```

Other Process:

```
insert into table customer_master select a, b, c;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, transaction is turned off in Hive. There is no conflict detections for different sessions updating the same data.

Statements in hive are just map-reduce(or spark, tez, etc.) jobs, they will run independently. Since they operate on the same table and in the end will write to the same directory, if the *insert into* job finish before the *insert overwrite* job, the first **result will be overwriten**. Because the *insert overwrite* job will clean the directory before writing the result.

To avoid this, use [hive transaction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions).